# align center a UL with only images

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, html-lists

I have a `<ul>` with 6 images, no text. I can't seem to make it be in the center of the page. This is my code.

**CSS**

```
.logos{ 
      margin:0 auto; 
      text-align:center;
      display:table;
      float: left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="logos" style="margin:0 auto;">
  <ul class="logos">
     <li class="logos"> <img src="imgs/logo1.gif"> </li>
     <li class="logos"> <img src="imgs/logo2.gif"> </li>
     <li class="logos"> <img src="imgs/logo3.gif"> </li>
     <li class="logos"> <img src="imgs/logo4.gif"> </li>
     <li class="logos"> <img src="imgs/logo5.gif"> </li>
     <li class="logos"> <img src="imgs/logo6.gif"> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
.logos{ 
      margin:0 auto; 
      text-align:center;
      display:table;
      float: left;
}
```

to

```
.logos{ 
      margin:0 auto; 
      text-align:center;
      display:table;

}
```

and the content will be in the middle of the page

Also you need to delete the `div` because is useless ,you set the same class to the `ul` and to `div`

Comment: thank you, it is centered now but vertically. i can't seem to make it centered horizontally... :(

Comment: @hal2001 to be in a line add  li {
    float: left;
}

Comment: i tried but it goes all left

Comment: Remove the DIV and the style code will be   .logos{ 
       margin:0 auto;
      text-align:center;
      display:table; 
        
}
li {
    float: left;
}

Comment: thank you, thank you, thank you. it works!

Comment: @hal2001 Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove the class name for div. `ul` and `div` have the same class name.

Give `float:left` to `li`

```css
.logos{ 
      margin:0 auto; 
      display:table;
}
.logos li{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="logos">
     <li class="logos"> <img src="imgs/logo1.gif"> </li>
     <li class="logos"> <img src="imgs/logo2.gif"> </li>
     <li class="logos"> <img src="imgs/logo3.gif"> </li>
     <li class="logos"> <img src="imgs/logo4.gif"> </li>
     <li class="logos"> <img src="imgs/logo5.gif"> </li>
     <li class="logos"> <img src="imgs/logo6.gif"> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```css
.logo_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.logos {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 0;
}
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo_wrapper">
  <ul class="logos">
    <li class="logo">
      <img src="imgs/logo1.gif">
    </li>
    <li class="logo">
      <img src="imgs/logo2.gif">
    </li>
    <li class="logo">
      <img src="imgs/logo3.gif">
    </li>
    <li class="logo">
      <img src="imgs/logo4.gif">
    </li>
    <li class="logo">
      <img src="imgs/logo5.gif">
    </li>
    <li class="logo">
      <img src="imgs/logo6.gif">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```